# How to create directory under my active theme directory

Tags: wp-admin

I want to added a directory under my active theme and then add file inside the newly created directory I need steps to avoid mistakes thank you

Comment: This is not a good idea as any files would be lost on theme update. Any dynamic files created by the theme should go in the uploads directory.

Answer (score 0):

Create a child theme or your active theme and then you can easily create Directory and it will not effect on theme updates